# Symfony/Silex + Facebook SDK : Session Start conflict

Tags: php, facebook, session, symfony, silex

How do I resolve session_start conflicts without changing the original source code? And how does the Symfony component or Silex check to see if a session already exists?

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in
myapp/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php on line 146
```

EDIT: here's the first few lines of index.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * from Heroku's Facebook template
 */
require_once('AppInfo.php');
require_once('utils.php');


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
use Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Currently using git submodule, will move to composer.json
 */
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
  'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
));

$app = new Silex\Application();
// ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FB sdk starts the session [only if it's not started already](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L36). Move the sdk initialization after the code that starts silex's session.

[This](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L538) is the function Symfony2 uses to see if the user has a session. In essence it checks the existence of a session cookie.

Comment: Thanks, and also for the link. It seems like your my go to guy for Silex related help ;)

Comment: I'm following the silex tag in rss, and help out when I can. :)

Comment: That solution is not possible or at least very, very ugly if you want to use facebook authentication, as the security has to take place before the request hits your controller.

Comment: The OP didn't use the security component.